# IntegrityErrorCode with Error Code -8 in Play Integrity

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-integrity-api, safetynet-api

I'm facing an issue with Play Integrity in my Android application. Specifically, I'm receiving an IntegrityErrorCode with the error code -8 and I'm struggling to find detailed information about what this error code signifies.

I've checked the Play Integrity documentation, but it doesn't provide specific details on each error code.

I was expecting get result code 0.
However, I'm still facing the IntegrityErrorCode -8 error. Can someone provide insights or solutions on how to handle this issue?

Comment: The error code -8 for Play Integrity corresponds to INTEGRITY_STATE_NO_DATA. This error code indicates that the Play Integrity API couldn't retrieve the integrity state of the device. could be network error, device not supported, play service on the device not updated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value -8 for `IntegrityErrorCode` is the error [`TOO_MANY_REQUESTS`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#TOO_MANY_REQUESTS).

The suggested mitigations are:

1. [Request a quota increase](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#increase-daily)
2. Implement a retry strategy with an incremental backoff